# Find the significance level for Z≤-2.0537

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

For specific values such as 1.6449 I can simply use a table to know that the significance level is 5%. How do I figure this out with values that aren't as common?

**EDIT**: Information that I initially left out,

Null Hypothesis: mean=3.55

Alternate Hypothesis: mean<3.55

n=49

Standard Deviation = 6.2

Eventually I get to P(X≤1.73)=α, and using the table I get a z value of 0.9582.

(With X being the critical value)

Comment: It´s about hypothesis testing ? We need more information. What is your confidence interval ?

Comment: I'm not given a confidence interval, but I added all the other information that I was given. I initially left it out as I was unsure what to use it for, other than getting my critical value.

Comment: And what is the sample mean ?

Comment: Please show also how you have got $X\leq 1.73$. I don´t want to play a Quiz.

Answer (score 1):

You need a more detailed table... or since it's the year 2000 use a software package that has the normal cumulative in it.

For instance I open an octave prompt and type: "normcdf(-2.0537)" and it gives me "0.020002".. looks like it's about 2%. R or Excel or pretty much any data analysis package will have the function implemented.

Wolfram alpha is a bit difficult  for getting the normal cumulative function for whatever reason, but I was able to get it to work: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=standard+normal+cdf+(-2.0537)

Comment: In R statistical software, `pnorm(-2.0537)` returns 0.02000237. The function `pnorm`, without additional parameters, is the standard normal CDF.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data sheet given here: [OCR List of Formulae](http://www.ocr.org.uk/Images/73472-datasheet-examination-formulae-and-statistical-tables.pdf) (page 19), we can read off that a z-value of 2.05 gives a p-value of 0.9798, and as shown by the extra columns to the right, if we wish to find a p-value for $z=2.054$, then add 2 onto the 4th decimal place of the previous result, which gives $p=0.9800$. So the significance level of such a test would be $2\%$.